# Not able to stream via newly created channel in liveBroadcasting

Tags: swift, live-streaming, agora.io

I am trying to dynamically create a channel and publish but its not sending stream on audience Apps

Below is the code snippet

````
func setUpVideo() {
        getAgoraEngine().enableVideo()
        getAgoraEngine().enableAudio()
        
        getAgoraEngine().setChannelProfile(.liveBroadcasting)
        
        //Warning: only enable dual stream mode if there will be more than one broadcaster in the channel
        //getAgoraEngine().enableDualStreamMode(true)
        
        if isBroadcaster{
            
            let videoCanvas = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
            videoCanvas.uid = userID
            videoCanvas.view = localVideoView
            videoCanvas.renderMode = .fit
            
            getAgoraEngine().startPreview()
            getAgoraEngine().muteLocalAudioStream(false)
            getAgoraEngine().muteLocalVideoStream(false)
            
            getAgoraEngine().setClientRole(.broadcaster)
            getAgoraEngine().setupLocalVideo(videoCanvas)
            
        }
        else{
            getAgoraEngine().setClientRole(.audience)
            getAgoraEngine().muteLocalAudioStream(true)
            getAgoraEngine().muteLocalVideoStream(true)
            
        }
        
        //Configuration
        getAgoraEngine().setVideoEncoderConfiguration(
                             AgoraVideoEncoderConfiguration(
                                size: AgoraVideoDimension640x480,
                                     frameRate: .fps30,
                                     bitrate: AgoraVideoBitrateStandard,
                                     orientationMode: .adaptative
                             )
                     )
        
    }
    ```
    ```
    func joinChannel() {
        
                let options = AgoraRtcChannelMediaOptions()
                        options.autoSubscribeAudio = true
                        options.autoSubscribeVideo = true
                        if (rtcChannel != nil) {
                                rtcChannel.destroy()
                        }
                        rtcChannel = getAgoraEngine().createRtcChannel("Test123213")
                        rtcChannel.setRtcChannelDelegate(self)
                rtcChannel.publish()
                        let success = rtcChannel.join(byToken: nil, info: nil, uid: 0, options: options)
        
                print(success)
        
            //APPROACH FROM https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/start_live_ios?platform=iOS
        /*if let name = userName {
            let channelCode =   getAgoraEngine().joinChannel(byUserAccount: name, token: tempToken, channelId: channelName) { [weak self] (sid, uid, elapsed) in
                //TODO: Hardik : Call API HERE for join
                self?.userID = uid
            }
            print("RTC---",channelCode)
        } else {
            let channelCode =   getAgoraEngine().joinChannel(byToken: tempToken, channelId:channelName, info: nil, uid: userID) { [weak self] (sid, uid, elapsed) in
                //TODO: Hardik : Call API HERE for join
                self?.userID = uid
                
            }
            print("RTC---",channelCode)
        }*/
        
        
        
    }
````

```
extension AgoraVideoViewController: AgoraRtcChannelDelegate {
    func rtcChannelDidJoin(_ rtcChannel: AgoraRtcChannel, withUid uid: UInt, elapsed: Int) {
        
            if !isBroadcaster{
                let videoCanvas = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
                videoCanvas.uid = uid
                videoCanvas.view = localVideoView
                videoCanvas.renderMode = .fit
                getAgoraEngine().setupRemoteVideo(videoCanvas)
            }
    }
 
    func rtcChannel(_ rtcChannel: AgoraRtcChannel, didJoinedOfUid uid: UInt, elapsed: Int) {
       
    }
 
    func rtcChannel(_ rtcChannel: AgoraRtcChannel, didOfflineOfUid uid: UInt, reason: AgoraUserOfflineReason) {
        
    }

    
    func rtcChannelDidLeave(_ rtcChannel: AgoraRtcChannel, with stats: AgoraChannelStats) {
        
    }
 
    func rtcChannel(_ rtcChannel: AgoraRtcChannel, didOccurWarning warningCode: AgoraWarningCode) {
       
    }
 
    func rtcChannel(_ rtcChannel: AgoraRtcChannel, didOccurError errorCode: AgoraErrorCode) {
        
    }

}
```

The callback reaches rtcChannelDidJoin but the audience role is not able to see remote video. However, both roles are able to join the channel. **createRtcChannel** returns  **0: Success**  for both roles

Can anyone please suggest the right approach to do it?. My requirement is to create a channel once the host joins it.
Reference :

https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/start_live_ios?platform=iOS
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Breakout-Class/blob/master/breakout-ios/AgoraDualChannels/AgoraDualChannels/Controllers/LiveRoomViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

`rtcChannelDidJoin` is the callback received when the local user successfully joins the channel. You need to set up the remote video in `didJoinedOfUid` instead, which is the callback you receive when a remote user joins. For the audience, the broadcaster is the remote user, not the local one.